# How to check if a node is at wrong/right place in xslt1.0?

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file:

```
<SAMPLE>
    <HEADER>
        <INV_ID>23</INV_ID>
        <PROCESS_CODE>00</PROCESS_CODE>
        <DATE>1234567</DATE>
        <TYPE>00</TYPE>
        <RULES>
            <ACTION>00</ACTION>
        </RULES>
    </HEADER>
</SAMPLE>
```

I just want to check that the next node of `<TYPE>` element should be `<RULES>`. If it is not then i would just like to print an error message. For example if there are any other node or element after TYPE element then it is an error.

Please suggest something. i tried sibling functions but didnt work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What XPath with sibling did you try?

Comment: well, i was trying name(following::HEADER/TYPE). By getting the name of the node which is coming after the TYPE element, i can easily throw an error, right? Above x-path isnt correct i guess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help knowing *where* you are when doing this test. Assuming you want to do this as the first thing, while still at the very top, try something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="SAMPLE/HEADER/TYPE and not(SAMPLE/HEADER/TYPE[following-sibling::*[1][self::RULES]])">
            <error>error message</error>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- continue -->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This throws an error **if** the TYPE element exists inside SAMPLE/HEADER **and** its immediate following sibling is **not** `RULES`.

Note that in a well-designed XML the order of siblings should not be significant; as long as RULES is a sibling of TYPE, the recipient should be capable of dealing with it.